# How do you double number in ruby for an iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Need to double each value in my array. I know double is not a command, but not sure what else to use.

```
 odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
  array.each do |x|
  x += double
  print "#{x}"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to create a new array

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
arr = odds.map{|x| x*2}   
arr.inspect
# => [2,6,10,14,18]
```

To modify the same array use [`Array#map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21)

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
odds.map!{|x| x*2}   
odds.inspect
# => [2,6,10,14,18]
```

Comment: It is still printing the same value

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 'double' as in multiply by 2, or double as in duplicate?

```
array = [1,3,5,7,9]
array.each { |x| print "#{x*2}"; }
```

But you probably want either a new array, or to map your existing array,

```
result = []
result = array.map { |x| x*2 }
#or
result = array.map! { |x| x*2 }
```

Here is an example of duplicate,

```
result = []
array.map { |x| result << x; result << x; } #duplicate
```

see here: http://www.natontesting.com/2011/01/01/rubys-each-select-and-reject-methods/

Answer (score 0):

### Doing the Simplest Thing Possible

The simplest thing to do is to simply iterate over your array with [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [Kernel#p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p). For example:

```
odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
odds.map { |i| p i*2 }
```

### Defining a Custom Method

If you need more control, you can create a custom method that handles a block or returns an enumerator. For example:

```
def double *array
  array.flatten!
  block_given? ? array.map { |i| yield i*2 } : array.map { |i| i*2 }.to_enum
end

enumerator = double 1, 2, 3
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>
enumerator.each { |i| p i }
#=> [2, 4, 6]

double(1, 2, 3) { |i| p i }
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

This is probably overkill for your use case, but it's a useful technique to know if you want to work with enumerators and blocks. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have found to do it is to times / equal it by 2. For example:

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
odds.each do |x|
    x *= 2
    print x
end
```